# "&percnt;" not recognized by IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

IE is not recognizing `&percnt;` entity in both 8 and 9 versions. I tested in two computers.

I read that it is implemented in IE here:
http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/PercntCharacterEntity

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [HTML ASCII Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp) you can just use `&#37;`, IE should play nicely with that :-)

Strangely though, according to the [Google doctype wiki](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/PercntCharacterEntity) `&percnt;` is supposed to be supported in all versions of IE from 6 to 8, so it should work in IE8

Comment: IE not working as its supposed to. What's new? This is still happening on IE9. =(

Comment: Both links are dead by now